# Indenting terminal/shell output

Tags: shell, terminal, command-prompt

I've customized the look/feel of my terminal prompt extensively so that it outputs the following (for development work):

`== [~/current/path] (git_branch_name) $`

I use the `==` to help identify the prompt lines when I'm looking at a big blog of text.

However, after using this for a few months, I find it's difficult to easily glance at the terminal and know what's what.

I had the idea that indenting all the output would help with that.  I know I can change the color as well, but wanted to play with both solutions.

But I have no idea how to indent all output that gets sent to the terminal.  MAN pages didn't help me and I couldn't find much on Google.

**What I am trying to do**

`$ some_command_that_outputs_text
  All lines of output are indented 2 spaces...
  All lines of output are indented 2 spaces...
  All lines of output are indented 2 spaces...
  All lines of output are indented 2 spaces...
$ another_terminal_prompt
  More lines are indented 2 spaces...
  More lines are indented 2 spaces...
  More lines are indented 2 spaces...
  More lines are indented 2 spaces...`

**Updated: 2014-10-24**

Note that I have already customized my color scheme for my terminal as well as the prompt itself.  I found that the color scheme wasn't enough for me personally to locate my commands as much of the text itself has similar coloring as my prompt itself.

Comment: If your goal is to make the prompts stand out, putting them in bold might be more effective. If you're using bash, you can add `\[\e[1m\]` to the beginning of `$PS` and `\[\e[m\]` to the end. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Printing-a-Prompt.html

Comment: @KeithThompson, you are correct.  I have already highly customized my entire terminal prompt and color scheme.  However, I've found that even that was not enough to easily glance at a mass of text and easily locate the last executed cmd.  It's mostly my personal preference, but I do employ both color-coded and now indented.  I'll play with the indenting for a while and see if it makes life easier :)

Comment: Hmm. Personally, I wouldn't want an environment that messes with the output of every command I run (which is not to suggest that you shouldn't be able to). And I wonder what effect it would have on full-screen commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your current `bash` you can do the following:

```
exec 1> >(sed -r 's/^(.*)/  \1/g')
```

Or use that if your `sed` implementation does not support the `-r` flag:

```
exec 1> >(sed 's/^/ /')
```

That redirects the standard output file descriptor (stdout) to `sed`, that adds two newline to every line of the outout. Try it with:

```
$ ls -l
  total 0
  drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 40 Oct 22 16:35 dir
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  0 Oct 22 16:59 file
$
```

Comment: Nice idea to use `exec`. sed command can be slightly simpler: `sed 's/^/  /'` (comment formatting doesn't show 2 spaces in the replacement part)

Comment: Is that something I can extract into a .bash_profile and use everywhere?  I started playing with the colored prompt and I like it, but I would like to try out indented output.  But in order for it to be "useful" I need to indent ALL output everytime I use a terminal. Note I haven't tried this yet, will get a chance to soon.

Comment: @DanL you could add that into one of your terminals rc-scripts. For example the `~/.bashrc`...

Comment: I wasn't able to get `exec 1> >(sed -r 's/^(.*)/  \1/g')` working inside my `.bash_profile`.  My terminal kept blowing up when it started (I use iTerm2).  Also, when I tried just executing the command in a running terminal, it broke: "sed: illegal option --r".  This may be a foolish question, but I was under the assumption I could just copy/paste `exec 1> >(sed -r 's/^(.*)/  \1/g')` into my `.bash_profile` and it would work...was that a bad assumption?

Comment: @DanL your sed implementation does not support the -r flag. Use `exec 1> >(sed 's/^/  /')` instead.

Comment: @chaos, this works for me!  Thanks for the solution. Are you aware of any complications with passing everything through `sed` like that?  I'm really just using it to assist with working with lots of text screaming by the screen and it takes me a second or 2 to find where I executed the last cmd.

Comment: You're welcome. That solution may break if you use other file descriptors than stdout. stdout is file descriptor 1. There are up to 9 descriptors. But they are not often used, and if they are used your output would not be indented. another thing is that `sed` reads input line by line. It may slow things down that have a huge load of output (thousands of lines).

Comment: If I where you I would work with colors only as you intended in your question.

Comment: Lots of programs check whether their output is to a TTY in deciding how to behave, so yes, this *will* have side effects. (It's particularly common to decide whether to turn on syntax highlighting this way).

Answer (score -3):

You can use tput to move the cursor to an absolute position.

```
tput cup x y
```

Where and x and y are the row and column positions before echo the output.

```
man tput
```

For details.

Comment: I tried this out and it seemed to be more complicated than it should be; I don't know if I could extract this into a common solution I could use for every terminal.

Comment: Really? Complicated? How?For example.

`tput cup 10 10; echo "This is a test"`

Puts "This is a test" exactly on row 10 column 10.
If that is complicated, then I don't know what is not complicated for what you have in mind.

Comment: it seems I have to enter the row/column dimensions every time for each line.  What I was looking for was a way to automate this and store it in a `.bash_profile`, so that every time I open a terminal and output something, it gets indented relative to my cmd prompt so I can easily see where my last commands were executed. The `sed` solution works very well, but I couldn't get `tput cup` to work as seamlessly.

Comment: @RJ, ...complicated to use it to actually achieve the effect that the question asks for, ie. indenting _each and every line_ of output, even when from a program that writes multiple lines.

Comment: So basically since you can't understand the use of tput, nor can use variables to automate the output you down vote? Seems not nice. Don't expect to helped a lot with such attitude.

Comment: @RJ, your solution does not satisfactorily resolve the original question. The other answer about using `sed` works very well, which is why I selected it as the answer.  The purpose of Stack Overflow is so other developers can come and find solutions to their problems. For my problem, your solution does not work. I'm not saying it's not a good solution for another problem, but for my specific problem it is not a good solution. Hope the clarification helps, and best of luck to you!

Comment: I understand the purpose of stack overflow. I have no problem if my solution was too hard for you, or was perceived as not the "best" solution. I was referring to down voting just because you or someone else was unable to understand it. We on stack overflow or similar sites down vote only WRONG answers or answers that distract, or intentionally or unintentionally misleading, not because we could not understand it.  Hope the clarification helps, and best of luck to you too.